# Finding the order of a pole of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

So many solutions on here seem to use the following result: if $f(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$, and\ $\lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)^{m}f(z)$ is finite and non-zero (or possibly just finite?), then $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$. How is this result proved?

Comment: Use the Laurent expansion of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$

Comment: $g(z)=(z-z_0)^{m}f(z)$ is analytic in some open disk around $z_0$. Use the power series expansion of this function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do you know it's analytic if we are just assuming the limit exists?

Comment: If $h$ is analytic in $\{z: 0<|z-z_0| <r\}$ and if $h$ is bounded in this disk then $h$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm incredibly confused. You are claiming that a function is analytic by saying "if it is analytic then...."? I also don't see how any of this matches up with the definition of order of a pole which I have been given, namely "if $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, we may write $(1/f)(z) = (z-z_0)^{m}g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic, $g(z_0) \neq 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We say that $m$ is the order of the pole of $f$ at $z_0$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} (z-z_0)^m f(z) < \infty$. This means that $(z-z_0)^m f(z)$ has at most (or worst if you will) a removable singularity at $z_0$. Make sure you understand why this is or prove it!

Consider tha Laurent series of $f$ around $z_0$:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$$

$$(z-z_0)^mf(z)  = (z-z_0)^m \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^{n+m}$$

Since, as we commented earlier, this function has at most a removable singularity at $z_0$, $a_n = 0$ for all $n+m < 0 \implies n < -m$, i.e.

$$(z-z_0)^m f(z) = \sum_{n=-m}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^{n+m}.$$

We divide by $(z-z_0)^m$ and get

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-m}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n,$$

which shows that $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$.